# Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement and syntax error that I can't find

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having trouble:

```
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:04 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.16.Final}
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:04 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spectacol1]
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, autocommit=true, user=root}
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: true
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 100 (min=1)
Wed Jun 06 23:45:05 EEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:05 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Hibernate: create table Ticket (id integer not null auto_increment, number integer, row integer, sold bit, spectacol_id integer, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at service.HibernateService.getSession(HibernateService.java:27)
    at controller.LoginController.<init>(LoginController.java:20)
    at gui.LoginUI.<init>(LoginUI.java:19)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'row integer, sold bit, spectacol_id integer, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:675)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 16 more

Hibernate: alter table distribution add constraint FKg8qnn50p2wnrbf0ust2v9u2f9 foreign key (actor_id) references Actor (id)
Hibernate: alter table distribution add constraint FKet3ybyohgnex9khfs89yl14dv foreign key (spectacol_id) references spectacol (id)
Hibernate: alter table Ticket add constraint FKs18bxl8vtsjlxglpk3kigfm6u foreign key (spectacol_id) references spectacol (id)
Jun 06, 2018 11:45:06 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at service.HibernateService.getSession(HibernateService.java:27)
    at controller.LoginController.<init>(LoginController.java:20)
    at gui.LoginUI.<init>(LoginUI.java:19)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'spectacol1.ticket' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:675)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 15 more
```

And this is my code :

```
package database;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name="Ticket")
public class Ticket {
    @Column(name = "row")
    private int row;
    @Column(name = "number")
    private int number;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "spectacol_id")
    private Spectacol spectacol;

    @Column(name = "sold")  
    private boolean sold;

    public Ticket(int row, int number, Spectacol spectacol,boolean sold) {
        this.row = row;
        this.number = number;
        this.spectacol = spectacol;
        this.sold = sold;
    }

    public Ticket() {

    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }
    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Spectacol getSpectacol() {
        return spectacol;
    }
    public void setSpectacol(Spectacol spectacol) {
        this.spectacol = spectacol;
    }

    public boolean isSold() {
        return sold;
    }

    public void setSold(boolean sold) {
        this.sold = sold;
    }



}
```

The problem seems to be with the creating of the table called **Ticket**.
I've checked for syntax errors but can't really find any. My application is bigger and the code runs, but when the application gets to the part of creating the **Ticket** table it seems to give me the error log I've posted above.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

row integer

row is a keyword in mysql. Choose a different column name.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R

Comment: Finally, this fixed it. Thanks a lot!